# LLVM how to set Attributes::NoUnwind to Function?

Tags: llvm, function-attributes

I think this is very simple question, but I can't resolve it. Very sad.
So. When I do

```
llc.exe -march=cpp test.bc
```

I get interesting test.cpp with this piece of code:

```
AttrListPtr func__Z2f1i_PAL;
{
 SmallVector<AttributeWithIndex, 4> Attrs;
 AttributeWithIndex PAWI;
 PAWI.Index = 4294967295U; PAWI.Attrs = Attribute::None  | Attribute::NoUnwind;
 Attrs.push_back(PAWI);
 func__Z2f1i_PAL = AttrListPtr::get(Attrs.begin(), Attrs.end());
}
```

But when I want to write string like `PAWI.Attrs = Attribute::None  | Attribute::NoUnwind;`

in my project, I got error  `IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands operand types are: llvm::Attributes = int` What I need to do?
All necessary headers included. [OS - Windows 7 x64, LLVM - 3.2]

Comment: I've done some research - this code compile well with LLVM 3.1, but not LLVM 3.2. But, I don't understand why.

Comment: So, I continue my project with LLVM 3.1. If somebody knows, why this code is writes with llc from LLVM 3.2, but dont matches the operands types - please, let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Are you working with LLVM 3.2, or with the latest ("top-of-trunk") version?

Comment: I downloaded LLVM source code from http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.2  in January 05 2013

Comment: If somebody faced same problem - my solution (in LLVM 3.2): `llvm::AttrBuilder *atbuild = new llvm::AttrBuilder();`
`atbuild->addAttribute(llvm::Attributes::NoUnwind);`
`llvm::Attributes atrbs = llvm::Attributes::get(context,*atbuild);`       `function->addAttribute(0,atrbs);`

Comment: Huh, haven't noticed your latest comment before I posted. In any case, you can just pass Attributes::NoUnwind to the Attributes::get method, you don't need the AttrBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the cpp backend generates this code. In any case attribute handing was changed in 3.2 (and will change again in 3.3). The proper way to get an attribute in 3.2 should be:

```
Attributes::get(Context, Attributes::NoUnwind)
```

(you can always pass any ArrayRef here as the second argument, to initialize the attribute set with multiple values).

The simplest way to add an attribute to a function would be:

```
Function->addFnAttr(Attributes::NoUnwind)
```

And if you want an `AttributeWithIndex`:

```
AttributeWithIndex::get(Context, ID, Attributes::NoUnwind)
// OR:
AttributeWithIndex::get(ID, Attributes::get(Context, Attributes::NoUnwind))
```

Comment: Some things went wront in VS:  "IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "llvm::AttributeWithIndex::get" matches the argument list argument types are: (llvm::LLVMContext, int, llvm::Attributes)" ...Last argument must be only ArrayRef ?

Comment: @kpdev I believe `function->addFnAttribute(Attributes::NoUnwind)` is the simplest way.

Comment: Oh, yes. `function->addFnAttr(...)` very simple. Thank you )

Comment: @kpdev you welcome! I've edited my answer to include that tidbit inside :)