# How to add an attribute group to a function call in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

When compiling a program with clang I observe the following in the LLVM IR:

Given the following function declaration:

```
declare i32 @atoi(i8*) #2
```

Which has the following attributes:

```
attributes #2 = { nounwind readonly "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
```

I can see that when the function is called:

```
%26 = call i32 @atoi(i8* %25) #5
```

More attributes get defined/re-defined for it:

```
attributes #5 = { nounwind readonly }
```

I know that the `#2` [attribute group](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#attribute-groups) contains "Function attributes" that can be added to a `Function` [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301964/llvm-how-to-set-attributesnounwind-to-function/16314114#16314114) the `addFnAttr(Attribute Attr)` method. I also know that there are "Return attributes" that I can add to a `CallInst` [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258741/adding-the-inreg-attribute-to-llvm-ir-function-parameters/35297742#35297742) `addAttribute(0, Attribute Attr)` as well as "Parameter attributes" that I can add with the same method or [with](https://llvm.org/docs/HowToUseAttributes.html) an `AttributeList`/`Set`. This gives me, for example, `%26 = call nounwind i32 @atoi(i8* nounwind %25)`.

But how are the attributes in the `#5` attribute group added? What are they called? Are they different from the other kinds of attributes? Are they redundant in this case?